# Missing SQL DLL's in C# Class Library Project (RAGE:MP)

Tags: c#, mysql, exception

I'm developing a game server in one of popular environments called "RageMP". I was trying to setup a data base connection using MySQL.Data NuGet package. Everything looks fine, code builds fine, but when the program is executing the MySQL "Connection.open" code it throws an exception. I googled a lot, moved SQL files to bin directory of my project, moved them into the server's runtime files. It fixed a problem with missing "MySql.Data.dll" file, but it still says that files are missing. I checked, and the proper files are still there in the directories. So i made the references in the project to them. Nothing changed so I installed the "missing" files from NuGet and it didn't solve the problem too. Here's the exception I deal with right now:

*System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.'
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.*

It is thrown in this code:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: well, do you have a database running and does that database exist and do you have permission to connect to it with that username/password?!

Comment: MySql.Data doesn't work well (or at all) on non-.NET-Framework platforms, but you can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ (which has a very similar API) instead.

Comment: thanks, i'll try that soon and will let u know how it works

Comment: @BradleyGrainger man, you are a lifesaver! It works perfectly, thank you so much for saving my time :))